# C# Return an object with an event

Tags: c#, events

I try to return an object in my event:

```
public class MyEvent : EventArgs
{
 public Channels number = new Channels(); // Channels is a class where i declared only variables( i try to return all variables inside this class)
 public MyEvent(Channels numero)
 {
  return numero;
 }
}
```

This code doesn't work and i don't know how to return an object which contains my variables of Channels.

Comment: You have created a constructor, which has no return type.

Comment: Do you have an `EventHandler<MyEvent>` somewhere? Can you show us how you're using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change that to:

```
public class MyEvent : EventArgs
{
 public Channels Number {get;}

 public MyEvent(Channels numero)
 {
   Number = numero;
   //return numero; You cannot use "return" in a CTOR!
 }
}
```

Then you can use it in an EventHandler like this:

```
void MyEventHandler( object sender, MyEvent e )
{
   // sender => object that raised the event
   // e => an instance of `MyEvent`, having a property, we can read.
   var channels = e.Number; // use the info
}
```

Of course you would have registered it, before it will be triggered:

```
someInstanceProvidingTheEvent.MyEventHappened += MyEventHandler;
```

Raising the event works something like this:

```
// assume we are in the class that offers the Event
public event EventHandler<MyEvent> MyEventHappened;

protected virtual void OnMyEventHappened( Channels chans )
{
    // You may want to add some error fortification, here
    MyEventHappened?.Invoke(this, new MyEvent(chans));
}

// raise it
public void SomeMethod(){
    var theChannels = new Channels();
    // yadda yadda
    // now it happens!
    OnMyEventHappened(theChannels);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your line `public Channels Number {get;}`, what does it means? There I cant recover an object which contains variables of Channels.

Comment: It's a readonly Property. It will be set in the constructor and from then on be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyEvent : EventArgs
    {
        public Channels _channels { get; set; }

        public MyEvent(Channels numero)
        {
            _channels = numero;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public Main()
        {
            Channels myChannels = new Channels();
            MyEvent _myEvent = new MyEvent(myChannels);

            var youWant = _myEvent._channels;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add some explanation of what you have answered